# "symbol lookup error:" when executing from different directory, otherwise working as intended when executed from build directory

Tags: c++, linux

I have a weird problem on Ubuntu Linux 18.04 that appeared after having run pytest a couple of times. The project is mostly c++, but it also generates pybind11 bindings and generates library files via CMake.

My goal is to force a program to output its files into a specific directory within the project folder, i.e. not in the same directory where the executable file is. I used to achieve that by running this command:

```
user@computer_name:~/Dev/project$ (cd /home/user/Dev/project/unittests/test_output && "/home/user/Dev/project/./executable" -pdbin /home/user/Dev/project/unittests/test_data/3v8x.pdb -mtzin /home/user/Dev/project/unittests/test_data/3v8x_phases.mtz && cd /home/user/Dev/project)
```

This command used to work as intended, until today, when I ran some instances of pytest. While pytest is able to complete all tests successfully, my aforementioned command does not work anymore and gives me this error:

```
user@computer_name:~/Dev/project$ /home/user/Dev/project/./executable: symbol lookup error: /home/user/Dev/project/./executable: undefined symbol: _ZN7library7Class11functionEv
```

**However, when I try to execute the executable in the build directory, like this:**

```
user@computer_name:~/Dev/project$ ./executable
```

**There is no error whatsoever and if I try to give the program its input, the program works as intended without any errors. However, it outputs the files in the build directory - the place where I don't want the output to go.**

For further confirmation, I tried to execute the program from another directory again without giving it any input:

```
user@computer_name:~/Dev/project/unittests$ .././executable
```

to be greeted yet again with this error:

```
.././project: symbol lookup error: .././project: undefined symbol: _ZN7library7class11functionEv
```

So far I've tried to rebuild entire project, generate new Makefiles etc.

I also confirmed that there are no issues with the program itself. Any ideas on how to fix this issue or alternative ways to direct output to different folder without having to pass specific output arguments to the program itself?

Comment: Please compare (and show) the results of `ldd /home/user/Dev/project/./executable` from both locations.

Comment: Another culprit might be `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` (check with `env`) or rpath (check with `readelf -d /home/user/Dev/project/./executable` and search for `DT_RPATH` or `DT_RUNPATH`)

Comment: What is "library class function" (with one or more `.`s or `::`s or `_`s in there - I don't pretend to know the mangling)? What library is that from?

Comment: Okay, I think you helped me narrow down the issue. 

When I do `ldd /home/user/Dev/project/./executable` in the build directory, the library associated with the executable is picked up from the build directory, i.e: 
`libexecutable.so (0x00007f5c7c19f000)`

When I do `ldd /home/user/Dev/project/./executable` in other directory, i.e. "~/Dev/project/unittests$", the output of ldd is: `libexecutable.so => /home/user/py3-devtools/install/lib/libexecutable.so (0x00007f45a6a54000)` sourced from different build directly, which is a requirement associated with the project.

Comment: Difference between these two library files, is that the new libexecutable.so contains a new function which I have added to the project, hence the linking error. This all makes sense now, many thanks. If it's not too much, any ideas how to fix the LD_LIBRARY_PATH?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `executable` to pick up the `libexecutable.so` next to it, you have two options:

- Configure `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to contain `/home/user/Dev/project`.
  This will make the dynamic linker search there before any other configured directories.
  Either do this globally or in a wrapper script.
- Compile `executable` with an rpath. This will make library lookups by `executable` look in the rpath first. If you pass the `-Wl,-rpath,'$ORIGIN'/..` flag (note the single quotes around `$ORIGIN`!), the dynamic linker will always find `libexecutable.so` next to `executable` first.